# Entity Framework DataContext doesn't unload the memory on IISWorker process Memory Leak?

Tags: entity-framework, memory-leaks, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web application written with MVC 5 + Entity Framework.

I've noticed , that each request to controller , that access EF data , server memory grows badly and Never released.

Lets say , I am starting application with 300MB memory , after 50 requests the process already almost 1.5GB.

the DB context is enclosed with using statement

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntitiesContext)
{
   var list = ctx.Answers.ToList();
   return list;
}
```

// At this point I'd expect context being disposed , and memory freed ,
  but this doesn't happens , more than that it never happens.

Same happens with Adding entities ...

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context itself won't account for a lot of memory, and it should be disposed if you are using a using() block. A bigger issue though would be returning lists of entities. The server will allocate memory to service the requests and won't release that memory as soon as the request is done, the data will go to garbage collection but the reserved memory allocated to IIS won't necessary saw-tooth back down. The issue is that it does show that a single request has the ability to require a lot of memory pretty quickly.

If this is a server callback, consider defining a view model specific to just the data you mean to display, then .Select() that data from your entities and return the list of view models. The same would go for Web API methods, define a DTO to return with just the data needed.

```
var answers = ctx.Answers
  .Select(a => new AnswerViewModel 
  {
    AnswerId = a.AnswerId,
    AnswerText = a.AnswerText,
    AnswerTypeName = a.AnswerType.Name, // For example, getting values from child references...
  }).ToList();
```

Returning entities will be very inefficient from both a performance and memory use point of view, plus you can easily run into lazy-loading issues if you attempt to use any references out of scope of the DbContext. (and performance issues if you reference them in-scope)

Also make sure you are filtering data with .Where() clauses to avoid loading too many rows, and consider things down the road where data size may grow significantly where you may want to consider supporting row limits or paging to avoid situations where the server grinds to a halt because there ends up being 2M Answer records that any number of users have the ability to request all of them.

Other than that, check for multiple contexts being created per request, as this does have a performance cost. I'd recommend reading up on IoC containers like Autofac, as it can be integrated into MVC and can manage the scope of a DbContext or unit of work wrapper for you to ensure that only one instance is created per request.